# Custom card view shape

Tags: java, android, xml, canvas, drawing

I have an idea for a card item. But I don't know what is the best way to implement this. I can't imagine, how to do this with xml (how to cut off that half of the circle?), or how to do this using canvas? Extend card view and redefine background or?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should set you down the right path: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html
It allows you to define how a custom image will stretch.

I recommend you use a dialog or custom view with the 9patch image set as the background.  If the custom view is a relative layout then you can just center the textview within the relative layout.

Alternatively, if you really don't want to use an image, you can create a custom view and override the onDraw method.  @see http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: Wow, nine-patch! I've totally forgot about this. Thanks!

About custom drawing, am I able to just override onDraw method of the card view (cause it's layout for the card view) or there are some hidden obstacles?